# Passing json array into jquery

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, arrays, json

Im having trouble formatting my json array in jquery and I cant seem to find a suitable answer.

I have a mysql database of users that is outputting thier user id and name in json format.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,info FROM users WHERE info like '$keyword%'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  $return[] = $row;

echo json_encode($return);
```

Resulting in this output:

```
[{"id":"1","info":"Mike"},{"id":"2","info":"Sally"},{"id":"3","info":"Ben"}]
```

my jquery success looks like this:

```
$.each(data, function()
{
  $.each(this, function(k, v) 
  {
    $('.results').append('<li id='+k+'>'+v+'</li>');
  });
});
```

resulting in this output:

```
<li id='id'>1</li>
<li id='info'>Mike</li>
<li id='id'>2</li>
<li id='info'>Sally</li>
etc...
```

But I would like it to read:

```
<li id='1'>Mike</li>
<li id='2'>Sally</li>
<li id='3'>Ben</li>
```

Ive been trying to wrap my brain around how to get this working but cant come up with anything, does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$.each(data, function() {
    $('.results').append('<li id="' + this.id + '">' + this.info + '</li>');  
});
```

However, DOM manipulation is slow, and whilst this won't be noticable for a small number of results, if you're adding a lot of `<li>`'s at the same time, you'll find the following code more efficient:

```
var str = '';
$.each(data, function() {
    str += '<li id="' + this.id + '">' + this.info + '</li>';  
});
$('.results').append(str);
```

Much easier than you thought, eh? :)

**Edit:** A brief description of why this works, and yours didn't:

What you've got is an array of objects. When you call $.each over `data`, it iterates through the array. Inside the callback function you pass to `each`, `this` is equal to the current element in the array; which is the object. So we access the `id` and the `info` attributes of the object (`this.id` and `this.info`), and build a `<li>` out of it.

Comment: I got the same, just 10 seconds later, haha!

Comment: I would +1 this again for proper explaining, alas I already up-voted this, hehe

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the inner `$.each` and doing:

```
$.each(data, function()
{
  $('.results').append('<li id='+this.id+'>'+this.info+'</li>');
});
```

Comment: I think you mean `this` and not `data`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider, an associative array from PHP is an object for JavaScript. 
Additionally, your JSON is absurd over sized. (indexed index)

```
var name=["Mike","Sally","Ben"];
for(var i=0;i<name.length;i++){//Yes, it has a length.
   $('.results').append('<li id='+i+'>'+name[i]+'</li>');
   }
```

would be enough. 
If you insist on your solution - you forgot some brackets.

```
[[{"id":"1","info":"Mike"}],[{"id":"2","info":"Sally"}],[{"id":"3","info":"Ben"}]]
```